# how to make images fit to window screen , ( which images are not in html files)

Tags: html, css

I know I should not post links here because it will not be useful for future use but I dont know how to ask, I dont have reputation to upload pictures.you all will excuse me please. 
I am working on a doctor site, this is patient picture.

http://www.drkhalilmd.com/images/photogallery-Breast-Aug/patient01/image-01-big.jpg

I am trying to fit this image to mobile width it is exceeding the width of browser and coming like this

http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/?u=http://www.drkhalilmd.com/images/photogallery-Breast-Aug/patient01/image-01-big.jpg
any help?

Comment: the picture is not a html file to add tags. it is in direct images folder   like www.domain.com/images/picture.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a class tag to the image like this:

```
<img class="boobPic" src="http://www.drkhalilmd.com/images/photogallery-Breast-Aug/patient01/image-01-big.jpg" />
```

Then add this to your css:

```
img.boobPic {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Since your image is within an iframe, the following will work too. However, it will also apply the properties to all the other images on the page though:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: the image is not in html file